# Is there a way to use IgnoreCase in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, uppercase, lowercase

I want to transnlate some words, but i have problems when I write HOUSE in uppercase or mixing. it just work when i write in lowercase

```
<script>
var translate = prompt("Enter one of the next words:\nhouse\ntable\ndog\ncat");

switch (translate){
    case 'house': document.write("casa");
        break;
    case 'table': document.write("mesa");
        break
    case 'dog': document.write("perro");
        break;
    case 'cat': document.write("gato");
        break;
    default: document.write("Error");


}
</script>
```

Comment: Obvious solution: `switch (translate.toLowerCase()){` (actually, not so obvious, because you also have to account for a closed dialog. So, the final solution becomes `switch (translate ? translate.toLowerCase() : '') {` )

Comment: @RobW wouldn't `undefined` fall into `default`?

Comment: @Shmiddty Not in the first case, because `undefined` has no string methods, so `undefined.toLowerCase()` causes an error to be thrown, which halts the execution of the script.

Comment: @RobW Ah yes, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified code. (As solution already given in comments. )

```
<script>
var translate = prompt("Enter one of the next words:\nhouse\ntable\ndog\ncat") || ''; // take '' if user cancel the prompt as it return `null`;
translate  = translate.toLowerCase();
switch (translate){
    case 'house': document.write("casa");
        break;
    case 'table': document.write("mesa");
        break
    case 'dog': document.write("perro");
        break;
    case 'cat': document.write("gato");
        break;
    default: document.write("Error");


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like toLowercase()

```
mystr="Hello WORLD !";
document.write(mystr.toLowerCase());
```

would give "hello world"

apply this to your translate variable

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase